# Retrieve a batch of images from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display 8 pictures from a column that contains filenames within a table, the tables are correct and the fields `interest_id` and `interest_pic` (where the filename is stored) are correct.

```
$interest_image_query = mysql_query("SELECT interest_pic FROM interest_pictures WHERE interest_id='$i_id'");
$i = 0;
while($interest_display_image = mysql_fetch_array($interest_image_query) && $i < 8){
  echo '<td><img src ="/uploads/images/interestpics/'.$interest_display_image['interest_pic'].'" width=60px height=60px /></td>'; 
  $i++;
}
```

The output seems to show the folder location but no filename. In this case `$i_id` = 20, and is verified and working. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How many rows does the query return if you run it in a gui or command line?

Comment: If you're only going to use 8 of these, may I suggest skipping `$i++` and instead just adding `LIMIT 8` to your query...

Comment: @case1352 It shows 1 row, and the correct filename

Comment: Do you envisage that the same picture will print 8 times?

Comment: @case1352 We are planning to add more pictures, but at the moment it won't even echo that one

Comment: And you have error reporting turned on, so you see query & connection failures?  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: echo this back to the screen "SELECT interest_pic FROM interest_pictures WHERE interest_id='$i_id'" to make sure that id is going in

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I tried to var_dump $interest_image_query and get "resource(10) of type (mysql result)"

Comment: @mobile Then `var_dump($interest_display_image)` inside the loop.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski echo mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT interest_pic FROM interest_pictures WHERE interest_id='$i_id'")); makes it show "Array"

Comment: @mobile I said to `var_dump($interest_display_image)` not `echo` it. You need to see the _contents_ of the array.

Comment: The Resource id #10 above is from var_dump on the () on interest_image_query, not on interest_display_image

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski shows "bool(true)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that the `&& $i < 8` is causing `$interest_display_image` to be set to boolean "true"

replaced with `if($i < 8){}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you ran mysql_select_db() to select the proper table? This works for me.

I also added a LIMIT to the query to only return 8 results and echoed the file name in parenthesis after the img tag to confirm it's pulling the file name.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db("tablename");

$i_id = 1;
$interest_image_query = mysql_query("SELECT interest_pic FROM interest_pictures WHERE interest_id='$i_id' LIMIT 8");

while($interest_display_image = mysql_fetch_array($interest_image_query, MYSQL_BOTH)){
    echo '<td><img src ="/uploads/images/interestpics/'.$interest_display_image['interest_pic'].'" width=60px height=60px /> (' . $interest_display_image['interest_pic'] . ')</td>';
}
```